# Convert and Insert varchar date from one table to another

Tags: sql-server, date

I want to insert date from one table to another. But the problem is, source table is having date stored as varchar and destination as date datatype.

Also I want to change the format of the date while inserting to destination.

```
Table1
Date varchar(80) null

Table2
Date Date null
```

Date in Table1 is stored in mm-dd-yyyy
I want to convert it into dd.mm.yyy and store it into Table2.

How should I convert it? 
I tried below, but its not working.

```
select CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),TRY_Convert(date,[Date]),104)
```

Answer (score 1):

If your destination table has a date field of `date` type all you should do is to convert your source data to `date` type and insert it.

The format `dd.mm.yyyy` that you want as output is NOT `date` format but a `string` and you can always get your `date` data from the second table using `convert` to string with the format 104 while selecting data from your second table like this:

```
declare @Table1 table ([Date] varchar(80) null);
insert into @Table1 values ('12-31-2001'), ('02-28-2002');

declare @Table2 table ([Date] Date null);

insert into @Table2
select convert(date, [date], 101)
from @Table1;

select convert(char(10), [date], 104)
from @Table2;
```

Here I used table variables and you should use your Table1, Table2 instead

Comment: I agree. You should never have to worry about the format how it stores. In fact, you don't care.. All you should care about is precision - date, datetime, or datetime2. Then the format you want for retrieving it.

Comment: I wish MS had given an option at DB or instance level to just change the default date format. But they have given it only at session level (SET DATEFORMAT)
If most of your use cases are for dd.mm.yyy, you might want to change the server regional settings. Alternate option could also be to change default language on the SQL instance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming style `104` is what you want, you just need one `convert()`:

```
select TRY_CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), [Date], 104)
```

Your question is confusing because you specify that the *source* is a varchar and the destination a date.  That would imply:

```
select TRY_CONVERT(DATE, [Date], 104)
```

I would also fix the table with the `varchar` "date" column so it uses the `date` data type.  That is the right way to store dates.  If you are going to store them as strings (which is occasionally necessary), then use YYYY-MM-DD format.  This is (almost totally) unambiguous and easily turned back into a date.

Comment: No Its not working. I cant change the column datatype, it will affect the system developed till now.

Comment: If you are unclear please tell me which part you didnt understand.

Comment: can you just tell me how to convert  mm-dd-yyyy to dd.mm.yyyy. that would be enough

Comment: @ThesK What Gordon (probably) wanted to tell you: If the the target column has got some kind of a **real** date type, there is no `dd.mm.yyyy` format. The internally stored value is not a string but a binary value. How this is *presented* to you is depending on your culture settings... So: Do not bother about the *target format*, just make sure, that you've got a *real date value*.

Comment: Hi Gordon, about your *use YYYY-MM-DD format. This is (almost totally) unambiguous*: Try this: `SET LANGUAGE ENGLISH;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-02' AS DATETIME);
SET LANGUAGE GERMAN;
SELECT CAST('2017-01-02' AS DATETIME);`. But if you change the target type to `DATE` it works correctly... Weird...

Comment: @Shnugo . . . Funny.  I thought the only exception was French.  In any case, YYYY-MM-DD is accepted as standard by ISO 8601 (the hyphens are optional), and I prefer the hyphens.